# Typescript - modify array values on destructuring

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Say I have this piece of code:

```
const [val$, err$] = partition(result => ...)(httpSource$)
const valid$ = val$.pipe(
    tap(() => ...),
    map(result => ...)
)
const error$ = err$.pipe(
    tap(() => ...),
    map(result => ...)
)
```

Can I avoid creating the `val$` and `err$` variables, by modifying the `partition` return value before assignment?

Comment: No, but why would you create two Observables anyway? There is already an error notifcation in the Observable model.

Comment: @ggradnig because I differentiate using a custom function (which is why I use `partition`). But maybe I can simplify. Could you expand on the "error notification"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is usually no need to partition an Observable just for the error handling. Instead, we can use the `throwError` creation function to create an error notification. Error notifications are handled separately in your `subscribe` call (the second parameter of `subscribe` is a function that is called on error).

A typical example for custom error handling could look like this:

```
$httpSource.pipe(
    mergeMap(res => 
        res.error ? 
            throwError(res.error) : 
            of(res.value)
    ),
    tap(next => ..., err => ...)
).subscribe(
     next => ..., 
     err => ...
)
```

I'm using `mergeMap`, because `throwError` creates an inner Observable that must be merged in the outer Observable. Note, that both `tap` and `subscribe` take a second argument for the error handling function.

*More about error notifications*: The [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) defines three types of notifications that can be passed along the chain. One of them is the *error* notification, that is defined as:

> [the error notification] indicates that the Observable has terminated with a specified error condition and that it will be emitting no further items

**Catching and rethrowing-errors**: If an error notifcation comes along the Observable chain, we can gracefully catch that error and convert it to a different notification by using `catchError`:

```
$httpSource.pipe(
    catchError(err => throwError(new CustomError(err)))
).subscribe(
     next => ..., 
     err => ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks. A doubt: if I throw a custom error type, on `subscribe` the error type could become `MyCustomType | HttpErrorResponse` (the latter comes from `HttpClient`), or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid error notifications currently have an `any` type. Maybe this will change in RxJS 7, but at the moment you have to manually typecast.

Comment: I know and I hope they'll improve on that. Anyway the type would become an union, like the one I wrote above, right?

Comment: If $httpSource can produce an `HttpErrorResponse` as a error notification, then yes, the error value can be this one or your custom type.

Comment: That's not to say that you have to only ever check for those two types. Each operator in the pipe may introduce new errors, for example the use of `first` may cause an `EmptyError`.

Comment: Thanks! Can I catch the HttpResponseError and rethrow my custom one using your example snippet ?

Comment: Sure, there is another operator for that case, I'll add it to my post

Comment: Thanks! Using throwError before catchError will make it do an additional step however. Right?